# How to use some type specific function (such as .size() for std::string or std::vector and so on) on something of template type?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

If possible, how could I use some type-specific function (such as `.size()` for: `std::string` or `std::vector` or ...) in a function with a template type, being sure that when I'll use that type-specific function I'm actually calling it with the correct type as argument? Maybe I'm wrong, and if it is, please explain to me what I have to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
std::string func(T& number) {
    if (typeid(T) == typeid(std::string)) {
        unsigned short int size = number.size();// !
        return " is a string";
    }
    else if (typeid(T) == typeid(int)) {
        return " is an int";
    }
    //...
}

int main() {
    std::string name = "Anthony";
    int age = 8;
    std::cout << name /*<< func(name) */<< '\n' << age << func(age) << '.';
    return 0;
}
```

I know that in the code above the line:

```
unsigned short int size = number.size();//(I need exactly '.size()')
```

doesn't make any sense (even the whole code doesn't make much sense) considering that I never use that value, but to find the size of the string (when it is a string!) is exactly what I need, and to not post a very long code that would make sense, I'm posting only this to make it give the error I've had when trying to compile, and in order to give you a minimal reproducible example. So please, don't say to me "just delete that line and your code will work").

Comment: If you have different implementation for different types, maybe it would be better to use overloading instead of templates? What you want can be done, it's just something that's rarely needed (or useful).

Comment: It is possible but not using `typeid`. You need to know the type has compile-time information.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `if (typeid(T) == typeid(std::string))`, use `if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)`. ( Similarly, `else if constexpr` instead of `else if`).

Regular `if` requires both branches to be valid, even if the condition is known at compile-time. `if constexpr` requires a compile-time condition, but allows the discarded branch to be invalid (only if the error is related to the template argument; every branch has to be theoretically valid for some template argument).

`std::is_same_v<T, std::string>` is similar to `typeid(T) == typeid(std::string)`, except it counts as a compile-time constant. `if constexpr` would reject the latter.

Comment: Or check if T is an STL container instead of individual types.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use a template here, simply specialize the template.

```
template <typename T>
std::string func(T& number);

template<>
std::string func<std::string>(std::string& number) {
    unsigned short int size = number.size();// !
    return " is a string";
}

template<>
std::string func<int>(int& number) {
    return " is an int";;
}
```

Usually you using a template you want to avoid using specific implementations for types though. Overloads would be preferrable for a limited set of types using type-specific implementations though.

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement is not restricted to `std::string`(as you have mentioned `std::vector` etc), you can use **SFINAE** as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<typeinfo>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include <type_traits>
//make sure that this overload is added to the set when T has a size() member function which is your requirement
template<typename T> 
auto func(T const& number) -> decltype((void)(number.size()), std::string())
{
    auto size = number.size();
    return " is a " + std::string(typeid(number).name());
    
}
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_fundamental_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>,std::string> func(T const& number)
{
    return " is a " + std::string(typeid(number).name());
}
int main()
{
    
    std::string name = "Anthony";
    int age = 8;
    double dage = 22.2;
    std::cout << name << func(name) << '\n' << age << func(age) << '.'<<"\n"<<dage << func(dage);
    
    //lets test it with vector 
    std::vector<int> vec= {1,2,3};
    std::cout<<"\nvec: "<< func(vec);
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/k9hwlyjN-)

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/k9hwlyjN-):

```
Anthony is a NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
8 is a i.
22.2 is a d
vec:  is a St6vectorIiSaIiEE
```